# Schema.org and ContactPoint use with validation failure: "All values provided for http://www.example.com/ must have the same domain."

Tags: url, schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool

[The documentation from Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data) about structured data has the following snippet:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "url": "http://www.your-company-site.com",
  "contactPoint": [{
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "telephone": "+1-401-555-1212",
    "contactType": "customer service"
  }]
}
</script>
```

But this snippet produces a failure with validation ([test here](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/)) on field `url` with the message:

> `http://www.your-company-site.com` (All values provided for `http://www.example.com/` must have the same domain.)

So, I have the same error for my own information on my website but I don't understand what is the error and how to correct this.

Do you have any idea on about why this error happens?

Comment: Have you replace http://www.your-company-site.com name to your domain name? Paste out your website link on comment.

Comment: Yes I change it, you can test the linked validator with this snippet and there is the same error with any domain name. Also there is no reference on 'example.com' in the snippet but the error message has 'example.com'. I also notice that when we put "PostalAddress" instead of "ContactPoint", there is no more error. I don't understand why.

Comment: So, on your actual webpage, does the `url` match the domain on which the page is hosted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as we know for now, this seems to be a bug in Google’s SDTT.

Even Google’s own example gives this error, and there is no error when omitting the `contactPoint`, although the `url` value stays the same.

Stack Overflow questions about the same issue:

- [Google SDTT error: “All values provided for http://www.example.com/ must have the same domain.”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40279203/1591669)
- [Google structured data error: “All values provided for http://www.example.com/ must have the same domain.”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40399076/1591669)

Comment: I looked for similar question without find anything, but i miss some topics... Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't give the error here. It does if you use the single-page markup and then adjust it to have different URL paths for each item; but then you're not meant to be doing that. The single-page list is meant to be literally a single page with a list of visible content for each item which has an id="item1" , id="item2" etc, and the Google can provide a link to "http://example.com/page#item1" if you click the relevant carousel item. What they won't allow "/item1" and "/item2". Those are separate pages, not a "single-page list". You can't separate the visible content and the metadata.